# Redirect based on bookmark link

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect, anchor

I have an old web application that's being migrated to a different system, and I need to ensure that the existing URLs are redirected to the new system.  (I'm using ASP.NET MVC2.)

Usually, I can just redirect to the homepage of the new site.  However, if the URLs link to a specific item, they use an HTML bookmark as follows:

```
http://server/old-system/#itemID
```

I have a lookup file and translation function to go from an "itemID" to a redirect URL, and I can accomplish the redirection using a RedirectResult.

But how can I get the anchor tag to the server as a query string parameter (anchor tags aren't sent in HTTP requests)?  I assume I'll need some kind of client-side javascript for this to invoke a separate server method, but I'm not sure how to do that translation.

(Note, the whole reason for doing this is that clients may have stored a bookmark link to an item.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `http://server/old-system/#itemID` is a page in your system you can do a quick translation in javascript.

```
window.location.href.replace('#','?link=');
```

or get the value and link to another page.

```
window.location = "http://server?itemID="+window.location.hash.replace('#','');
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had started doing indexOf and substr calls on 'href'; this is a lot cleaner. :)